# Discover all modules in Nancy ConfigurableBootstrapper

Tags: c#, nancy

I want the ConfigurableBootstrapper to discover all my modules rather than have to list them all. I cant find the property for this. I dont want to have to list the type array explicitly

```
  var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(with =>
            {
                with.Modules(new Type[] {typeof (CompanyModule), typeof (UserModule)});
                with.Dependency<IDocumentSession>(RavenEmbeddedStore.Instance.Store.OpenSession());
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `AllDiscoveredModules()` is the method you need:

```
var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(with =>
        {
            with.AllDiscoveredModules();
            ...
        });
```